# Is it safe to store data on cloud?

Tags: cloud

I found that there are two types regarding cloud security.

```
     1.Security issues faced by cloud providers(organizations providing software-, platform-, or infrastructure-as-a-service via the cloud) 
     2.Security issues faced by their customers (companies or organizations who host applications or store data on the cloud).
```

It says data are securely encrypted and stored on the other hand it says government can request information which are stored in the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data's as safe in the cloud as you make it, just like anywhere.  You should always encrypt sensitive data in flight and at rest.  That way if someone accesses it, at least they can't read it.

Yes, I suppose the government can ask for it, but that's true of anything anywhere.  They can always *ask*.  If they get a warrant or a subpoena though, that's a different story.  They're no longer asking.  And in those situations your data wouldn't be any safer in a traditional data center or in your basement.  If it's encrypted though, they'll still have the hassle of decryption before it's of any use to them.

If this is a serious concern for you, you'll definitely want to carefully read any eula's before clicking "Agree" and then probably talk to a lawyer about your specific situation.  They'll know more about what the government can and can't do than most of the developers here (I'm guessing).

Otherwise, think of storing your data in the cloud like putting your valuables in a bank's safe deposit box.  Anyone can ask to get in there, but banks (and clouds) don't just give access like that out because it would ruin their business model.  Lots of companies currently use the cloud to store (encrypted) PCI and HIPAA data and it seems to work just fine for them.